# Can't select shape by name using cell value

Tags: excel, vba, cell, shapes

I've made several attempts to select a shape (image) on the sheet by it's name.

I have image names as barcodes, I've tried to convert shape name to double, then I've added Picture to each shape name and converted cell value to string.

I tried `StrComp` function with `vbText` and `vbBinary` options.

I’ve also tried to check types of the Shape.Name and Cells.Value. They are 8 (String) and 5(double). When I assign number to variable a (type 3 - LongInt) # is added, when macros is run, and then select Shape.Name(cStr(a)) it works(

```
For i = 2 To 224
    Sheets("Pilot products").Activate
    a = CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 9).Value)

    'a = CLng(a)
    'MsgBox (VarType(a))
    'Sheets("images").Activate
    For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If CStr(sh.Name) = CStr("Picture " + a) Then
        sh("Picture " + a).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Pilot products").Cells(i, 10).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Else: MsgBox CStr(a)
        End If
    Next sh

Next i
```

Comment: [String concatenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ampersand-operator) in VBA  is `&`.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Shapes from List (Dictionary)

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyShapes()
    
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        ' Allow case-insensitivity e.g. 'Picture = PICturE'.
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        ' Define workbook.
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
        ' Define Source Worksheet.
        Dim src As Worksheet
        Set src = wb.Worksheets("Images")
        ' Write the names of its shapes to the Dictionary.
        Dim shp As Shape
        For Each shp In src.Shapes
            .Item(shp.Name) = Empty
        Next shp
        ' Check if any shapes were found.
        If .Count > 0 Then
            ' Define Destination Worksheet.
            Dim dst As Worksheet
            Set dst = wb.Worksheets("Pilot products")
            ' Declare variables.
            Dim i As Long
            Dim ShapeIndex As String
            Dim ShapeName As String
            ' Loop through cells containing the shape indexes and copy
            ' the found shapes in the Dictionary from Source Worksheet
            ' to Destination Worksheet.
            For i = 2 To 224
                ShapeIndex = CStr(dst.Cells(i, 9).Value)
                If ShapeIndex <> "" And ShapeIndex <> "0" Then
                    ShapeName = "Picture " & ShapeIndex
                    If .Exists(ShapeName) Then
                        src.Shapes(ShapeName).Copy
                        dst.Paste Destination:=dst.Cells(i, 10)
                    Else
                      ' A shape (picture) with this number doesn't exist.
                    End If
                Else
                  ' NumStr is either "" or "0".
                End If
            Next i
        Else
          ' Dictionary is empty i.e. no shapes found.
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

If you're not too familiar with the Dictionary object you should rather use it like this:
(Note the '*** indicating the changes.)

```
Sub copyShapes2()
    
    Dim dict As Object '***
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") '***
    ' Allow case-insensitivity e.g. 'Picture = PICturE'.
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare '***
    ' Define workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    ' Define Source Worksheet.
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Set src = wb.Worksheets("Images")
    ' Write its shape names to the Dictionary.
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In src.Shapes
        dict(shp.Name) = Empty '***
    Next shp
    
    If dict.Count > 0 Then '***
        ' Define Destination Worksheet.
        Dim dst As Worksheet
        Set dst = wb.Worksheets("Pilot products")
        ' Declare variables.
        Dim i As Long
        Dim NumStr As String
        Dim ShapeName As String
        ' Loop through cells containing the shape indexes and copy
        ' the found shapes in the Dictionary from Source Worksheet
        ' to Destination Worksheet.
        For i = 2 To 224
            NumStr = CStr(dst.Cells(i, 9).Value)
            If NumStr <> "" And NumStr <> "0" Then
                ShapeName = "Picture " & NumStr
                If dict.Exists(ShapeName) Then '***
                    src.Shapes(ShapeName).Copy
                    dst.Paste Destination:=dst.Cells(i, 10)
                Else
                  ' A shape (picture) with this number doesn't exist.
                End If
            Else
              ' NumStr is either "" or "0".
            End If
        Next i
    Else
      ' Dictionary is empty i.e. no shapes found.
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It’s awesome. Will try it soon. Didn’t expect so detailed answer so fast. Thank you very much! I was really in despair today and spent a lot of time seeking for solution!

Comment: Everything worls. I only haven't understand the line .Item(shp.Name) = Empty..

Comment: It adds the shape name to the dictionary. The dictionary holds a value pair usually referred to as `Key` and `Value`: `.Item` is the `Key` and `.Item(Key)` is the `Value`. The line is writing the shape name to the `Key` and `Empty` to the `Value`, because we don't need the `Value`. Learn about the dictionary [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/).

Comment: I've added a slightly changed version with a more friendly usage of the dictionary. You should use this way while familiarizing yourself with it.

Comment: Thank you! I had an idea of the key, but the way new element was added confused me, like I expected something like .add or .append... And moreover I thought, that VBA doesn't support dictionaries and didn't think this way first, and second couldn't imagine to use shape.name as key, not as an element.